# Windows XP asking for password to access to Windows 10 shared folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, network-shares, shared-folders

I shared a folder from my windows 10 machine with windows xp machine.

I can ping both machines. and when I type the IP address of my xp machine in the windows 10 search bar it works and I can access to shared folders but the reverse doesn't work.

when I type the IP address of windows XP in the search bar of windows 10 I have this window :

[image: connect windows xp]

I specify that I do not have the option to turn off the password in all networks because I'm connecting to a domaine

[image: all networks]

I've Everyone in groups permissions with full control

[image: permissions]

also in Sharing -> Advanced sharing -> Permissions

[image: share permissions]

I tried the user name and password of my win10 session but it doesn't work !

Comment: In Windows 10, you must enable network discovery before it will work.

Comment: @LPChip network discovery is already enabled

Comment: You need to enable TLS 1.0 in Internet Options/Advanced